# Transfer of energy from radiated to conducted

Tags: quantum-mechanics, radiation

Can a CO$_2$ molecule in the atmosphere that has been heated by the earth's radiation, transfer that energy to one of the many O$_2$ or N$_2$ molecules nearby? If so, what is the mechanism?

Comment: Just FYI on global warming basics, the visible light sneaks by the CO2 during the day and all that visible light warms the earth and oceans. The earth and oceans convert the heat to IR ... and then the C02 scatter it around so it has a hard time getting back to outer space ... hence the global warming.

Comment: Yes, I know. If you look at Koonin’s book “Unsettled” you will see that if CO2 increases from 400 to 800 ppm there would be virtually no impact on the greenhouse gas effect. I need to understand exactly why he believes that is true.

Comment: https://skepticalscience.com/lacis-responds-to-koonin.html  lots of info here that may be of interest.

Comment: In general we just look at the absorption spectra for each molecule to see where it absorbs.  At night all the action is in the IR ... just longer wavelength photons coming from the ground/ocean trying to get to space .... if such a photon is absorbed and remitted (or just scattered is also important) it slows the cooling each  night.  The IR is everywhere and all molecules are responding to it.  It takes complex models/modelling to determine effects ....

Answer (score 1):

The heated $CO_2$ molecule would have higher Kinetic Energy, from $K.E =\frac{3kT}{2}$.

The mean free path of air molecules at STP is about $10^{-7} m$, so simply by colliding with the other molecules the carbon-dioxide molecule would transfer some of that energy.

There would be other mechanisms such as infra-red re-radiation, but the collision process would be quick and transfer energy to the other molecules.

This website has more detail

https://scied.ucar.edu/learning-zone/how-climate-works/carbon-dioxide-absorbs-and-re-emits-infrared-radiation

and says

"Molecules are constantly in motion, colliding with other gas molecules and transferring energy from one molecule to another during collisions. In the more-complex, real-world process, a CO2 molecule would most likely bump into several other gas molecules before re-emitting the infrared photon."

Comment: Yes but, the energy released from the CO2 molecule is at a very specific frequency that is related to 15 micro meters. O2 and N2 are transparent to that frequency so the released wave is transmitted either to space or the earth. In doing so it warms the earth but not the atmosphere.....at least directly. I was wondering if, somehow, the vibrations of the "hot" CO2 molecule might cause the surrounding O2 or N2 to absorb that energy thru Brownian motion.

Comment: @Barry Rodgers Yes, it seems that collisions or Brownian motion would be the main mechanism